# Filter array data

Tags: javascript

I'm new to ES6 and I have one problem, I have a nested array and I want to filter the data based on checked checkbox input.

```
const data = [
    { name: 'Airplane', type: 'folder', folderId: 1 },
    {
        name: 'Car',
        type: 'folder',
        folderId: 2,
        children: [
            {
                Name: 'BMW',
                type: 'folder',
                folderId: 3,
                children: [{ Name: 'X5', type: 'file', folderParentId: 3 }]
            },
            { Name: 'Toyota', type: 'file', folderParentId: 2 },
            { Name: 'Mazda', type: 'file', folderParentId: 2 },
            { Name: 'Ferrari', type: 'file', folderParentId: 2 }
        ]
    }
]
```

So I need to get:

> **CASE I:** If **X5** is checked and it is the only child, I need get the parent's information:

```
{
    Name: 'BMW',
    type: 'folder',
    folderId: 3
}
```

> **CASE II:** If **Toyota and Ferrari** are checked, I need to get the selected children:

```
{
    Name: 'Toyota',
    type: 'file',
    folderParentId: 2
},
{
    Name: 'Ferrari',
    type: 'file',
    folderParentId: 2
}
```

> **CASE III:** If **all children and all subfolders** are checked, I need to get the selected grandparent:

```
{
    name: 'Car',
    type: 'folder',
    folderId: 2,
}
```

After function for checkbox I got an array like:

```
const checked = [
{ name: 'Car', type: 'folder', folderId: 2}
{ name: 'BMW', type: 'folder', folderId: 2}
{ Name: 'X5', type: 'file', folderParentId: 3 }
{ Name: 'Toyota', type: 'file', folderParentId: 2 }
{ Name: 'Ferrari', type: 'file', folderParentId: 2 }
]
```

I try:

```
checked.filter(item=>item.folder === folderParentId && item)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share the code that you've tried. Read about how to create a [mcve] and update the question. StackOverflow is not a free coding service :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to get requested object.

```
function getObject(array, key, value) {
    var o;
    array.some(function iter(a) {
        if (a[key] === value) {
            o = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    });
    return o;
}
```

You can test `getObject(data,'name','Car');`